# HTML Block and Inline Elements text selection in watir

Tags: ruby, watir

how can I send a text in an HTML block and inline elements?

```
<gr_block p="0,7" style="display: inline;">My text</gr_block>
```

this also is connected to it

```
<span data-text="true">My text</span>
```

this is the messenger of facebook I'm trying to send a message via Watir. any ideas?
[Messenger](https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/)

update:

```
<div class="_5rp7 _5rp8" spellcheck="false">
<grammarly-ghost spellcheck="false">
<div data-id="d0205e5d-3e42-7f18-fa89-538e297341b2" data-gramm_id="d0205e5d-3e42-7f18-fa89-538e297341b2" data-gramm="gramm" data-gramm_editor="true" class="gr_ver_2" gramm="true" contenteditable="true" style="position: absolute; color: transparent; overflow: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap; border-radius: 0px; box-sizing: content-box; height: 19px; width: 307.951px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; z-index: 0; border-width: 0px; border-style: none; background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); top: 0px; left: 0px;" width="307.951416015625">
<span style="display: inline-block; font: 400 14px/17.92px &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: transparent; overflow: hidden; float: initial; clear: none; box-sizing: border-box; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; letter-spacing: normal; text-shadow: none; height: 19px;">
<gr_block p="0,16" style="display: inline;">My text</gr_block>
</span><br></div>
</grammarly-ghost>
<div class="_5rpb"><div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_8" aria-describedby="js_1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Type a message..." class="notranslate _5rpu" contenteditable="true" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; z-index: auto; position: relative; line-height: 17.92px; font-size: 14px; transition: none; background: transparent !important;" data-gramm="true" data-txt_gramm_id="d0205e5d-3e42-7f18-fa89-538e297341b2" data-gramm_id="d0205e5d-3e42-7f18-fa89-538e297341b2" data-gramm_editor="true"><div data-contents="true"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="fenr1" data-offset-key="8b6hl-0-0"><div data-offset-key="8b6hl-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="8b6hl-0-0"><span data-text="true">My text</span></span></div></div></div></div><grammarly-btn><div class="_1BN1N Kzi1t BD-0J _7_mnr MoE_1 _2DJZN" style="z-index: 2; transform: translate(294.951px, 5px);"><div class="_1HjH7"><div title="Protected by Grammarly" class="_3qe6h">&nbsp;</div></div></div>
</grammarly-btn></div>
</div>
```

Second element

```
<div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_8" aria-describedby="js_1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Type a message..." class="notranslate _5rpu" contenteditable="true" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; z-index: auto; position: relative; line-height: 17.92px; font-size: 14px; transition: none; background: transparent !important;" data-gramm="true" data-txt_gramm_id="d0205e5d-3e42-7f18-fa89-538e297341b2" data-gramm_id="d0205e5d-3e42-7f18-fa89-538e297341b2" data-gramm_editor="true">
```

My text

Comment: Question is not clear, you want to send the text to the above element like you send the text to text field?

Comment: yes that's exactly what i want .. there is no text field to send my text to . the only thing that the text is stored is that element

Comment: You gave two element and also I don't have anything to locate that element , give more HTML element along with this element give more ancestors. Update your question with enlarging the HTML.

Comment: provided the HTML elements of the HTML interface. I provided a link to messenger you can easily see these elements in much more details.

Comment: Okay so you want to set your own text in the place of my text, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible by webdriver because webdriver doesn't change the content of the page, but it's possible by Java script.

Write the below code

```
element=b.element(xpath: "//span[text()='My text']")
b.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText='Your Text here'",element)
```

`Your Text here` will appear in the place of My text.